# Show the Polar Factor is the Closest Unitary Matrix Using the Spectral Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

For a square matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ with the singular value decomposition $A = U\Sigma V^*$, I want to show that

$$\|A - P \|_{2} \leq \|A -W \|_{2}$$

Where $P = UV^{*}$ and $W$ is an arbitrary unitary matrix.

It is immediately clear to me that

$$\|A - P \|_{2} = \|U\Sigma V^* - UV^{*}\|_2 = \|\Sigma - I \|_2 $$

I also know that the singular values of all unitary matrices are all one. However, I don't know how to combine this fact with properties of the spectral norm to get a proof, if this is indeed the right way.

Comment: You may find the proof [here, Theorem 1](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1955-006-01/S0002-9939-1955-0067841-7/S0002-9939-1955-0067841-7.pdf).

Comment: @A.Γ. , Thank you for this.